# Rails: Calling URL helpers with string keys controller, action is deprecated. Use symbols instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im getting a:

> "DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling URL helpers with string keys controller,
>   action is deprecated. Use symbols instead"

When running unit tests, I looked around at this and while im new to rails I haven't exactly nailed down a ton of examples of this. It seems to come from the params symbols usually but a lot of the google results are complaining that this is an erroneous warning?

In my case it's complaining about this particular line:

```
<%= link_to exports_path(params.merge(format: 'xlsx')), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xls" do %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>Export XLXS</a> &nbsp; <% end %>
```

Im assuming it's complaining about the `params.merge(format: 'xlsx'))` but I don't understand why? Usually i've seen this error when symbols are used but there are no symbols being used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `action` and `controller` are string keys in the `params` hash.

```
params = {'controller': 'home', 'action': 'index'}
```

So when you merge your extra key to this hash you get this deprecation warning. However you should build the hash you want to send into your `link_to` in a safer way. E.g. in your controller

```
@my_params = {}
@my_params[:format] = 'xlsx'
@my_params[:name] = params[:name]
```

And then in your view

```
= link_to exports_path(@my_params)
```

Then you have total control over what goes into your query string.

Edit:

If you need a subset of what's in your `params` you can filter the `params` hash with the keys you need, like if you need `name` and `search` you do this.

```
@my_params = params.slice(:name, :search)
@my_params[:format] = 'xlsx'
```

Comment: So if I set it to `@my_params[:format} = 'xlsx'` what would I replace in my line of code with @my_params? (sorry im very new to rails, im just typically writing testing code so controllers/etc... is still new to me)

Comment: What is it in your `params` that needs to be part of the query string?

Comment: Sorry this is really old....but what purpose does [:name] hold. Your fix actually worked but I found that the @my_params[:name] was not necessary?

Comment: @msmith1114 I'm sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean. Did you just put `params` into the `link_to`?

Comment: I did this:
`@my_params = {}`
`@my_params[:format] = 'xlsx'`

and then just added @my_params into the link_to (I didn't do the `@my_params[:name] = params[:name]`)

So I wasn't sure what purpose the `@my_params[:name] = params[:name]` served